# material_design_icons_flutter ^4.0.5955 doesn't show the icons

Tags: flutter, material-design-icons

here is my code

```
Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.sms_outlined))),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(MdiIcons.rocket)),
```

but it shows nothing:

[image]

instead, Icons shows normally :
here is the code

```
Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Tab(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                        ),
                      ),
```

the image of a normal icon :

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use `flutter clean` and then build the application again? Most of the times the issue with icons when you upgrade package is with the cache. You need to clean and then build to see if the problem really exists.

Comment: no, i didn't but I added //@dart=2.9 and it works perfectly.